# torch7: How to get the dimensionality of a tensor?

Tags: lua, torch

Given any torch7 tensor, how can one find its dimensionality?

I want to apply it to check if a particular tensor is one-dimensional or not, but I am curious about any tensor in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t:dim()
```

I suggest that you read the documentation here: https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md

Answer (score 0):

if x.ndim == 1:
x = torch.unsqueeze(x,-1) #if x is one dimension, make it two dimensional